# Writing an IPython notebook extension that can run an analysis on every cell

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write an IPython notebook extension that will run analysis on the code in each cell and will then output messages via the logger (this could be for example a PEP8 analysis, to take a simple example). The catch is that I want to be able to load the extension once at the top of the notebook and have it apply to all cells.

It is possible to define custom line and cell magics (see [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#defining-your-own-magics)) but one has to put the magic command in each cell whereas I would like it to apply to all code cells.

I also found that it's possible to register a class that pre-filters code input, using `ip.prefilter_manager.registre_transformer` but that operates on a line by line basis which is not good enough.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to register a function that can analyze the content of all cells, when they are executed, and add logger messages to the output of that given cell?

I know there is a PEP8 extension for IPython notebook but this requies that the magic %%pep8 command be put inside each cell to be checked, and I want to change this to be more of a global setting in the notebook.